# Determine the probability that a randomly chosen employee will choose no supplementary coverage.

Tags: probability

Determine the probability that a randomly chosen employee will choose no supplementary coverage.

An insurer offers a health plan to the employees of a large company. As part of this plan, the individual employees may choose exactly two of the supplementary coverages $A, B$, and $C$, or they may choose no supplementary coverage. The proportions of the company's employees that choose coverages $A, B,$ and $C$ are $\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3},$ and $\frac{5}{12}$ respectively.

Attempt:
If $P(A) = 3/12$, $P(B) = 4/12$, $P(C) = 5/12$, $P(A)+P(B)+P(C) = 3/12 + 4/12 + 5/12 = 1.$ Got stuck.
Two question:
the answer should be $1 - P(A \cap B) + P(B \cap C) + P(B \cap C) =$ no coverage but

1. Can I derive $P(A \cap B)$ from this information?
2. is $A=3/12$ correct?

Comment: The question in the title is "Determine the probability that a randomly chosen employee will choose no supplementary coverage".  You state that "The proportions of the company's employees that choose coverages A, B, and C are 1/4, 1/3, and 5/12 respectively".  You then calculate that 1/4+ 1/3+ 5/12= 1.  That is, [b]every[/b] employee chooses at least one of the coverages.  The probability that an employee chooses no coverage is 0.

Comment: @user247327 That is over counting by quite a bit.

Comment: how do I derive how many employee chooses (A and B) = ? when Employee chooses plan A=  1/4, and employees chooses plan B =  1/3?

Comment: @DavidHang You don't need to (though you *may* if you like).  See my answer and realise $\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(B\cap C)+\mathsf P(A\cap C) = \boxed{\qquad?}$

Comment: P(A)+P(B)-P(A $\cup$ B) + P(B) + P(C) - P(B $\cup$ C) + P(A) + P(C) - P(A $\cup$ C) \\                                                                                 2(P(A)+P(B)+P(C)) = P(A $\cup$ B)+  P(B $\cup$ C) + P(A $\cup$ C)\\
     (P(A)+P(B)+P(C)) = 1/2

Answer (score 1):

You are given $\mathsf P(A)=\tfrac 14, \mathsf P(B)=\tfrac 13, \mathsf P(C)=\tfrac 5{12}$, but also know $\mathsf P(A\cap(B\cup C)^\complement)=0=\mathsf P(B\cap(A\cup C)^\complement)=\mathsf P(C\cap(A\cup B)^\complement)$

You also know $\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)=0$

I suggest drawing a Venn diagram to see that:

$$\mathsf P(A) = \mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(A\cap C) \\ \mathsf P(B) = \mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(B\cap C) \\ \mathsf P(C) = \mathsf P(A\cap C)+\mathsf P(B\cap C)$$

As the only regions that are not of zero probability are where exactly two sets overlap, and the area outside all three.   The areas covered by only one set, or by all three, have zero probability.

Which means that $\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement\cap C^\complement) = 1-\color{purple}{\boxed{\qquad\qquad?}}$

Answer (score 0):

P(A)+P(B)-P(A $\cup$ B) + P(B) + P(C) - P(B $\cup$ C) + P(A) + P(C) - P(A $\cup$ C)

2(P(A)+P(B)+P(C)) = P(A $\cup$ B)+  P(B $\cup$ C) + P(A $\cup$ C)

(P(A)+P(B)+P(C)) = 1/2

1 - (P(A)+P(B)+P(C)) = 1/2 probability that a randomly chosen employee will choose no supplementary coverage